# How to get the "true" LastModifiedDate of an object with the Salesforce API

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, last-modified, force.com

I have a Custom Object in Salesforce that users routinely access and edit within the Salesforce online environment. Lets call them **RootObjects** to keep things simple.

I am attempting to retrieve the "LastModifiedDate" the **RootObjects** using the Salesforce API. The goal is to determine when they were last edited by a user, however, I've hit a snag.

These objects have a Lookup relationships other custom objects. Lets call these **LinkedObjects**. When I insert a **LinkedObject** using the Salesforce API, it appears to effect the LastModifiedDate of the **RootObjects**, even thought I am not directly editing them the **RootObject**.

This is causing an issue whereby I cannot determine when a user last edited something vs. when a new related object was inserted.

Is there another system field that I can use that only reports the "true" last modified date? At this point, I am considering making a custom date field that is updated with a trigger whenever an object is saved, however, I would like to avoid that if necessary.

Comment: sounds like you have a trigger on LinkedObject that updates root.

Comment: Do you know the reason for the LastModifiedDate change on the RootObjects? Do you have a Trigger or Workflow on or involving the LinkedObject?

Comment: I don't believe I have any Workflows or Triggers that would affect the RootObjects when a related object is added, however, I will check with my team to make sure. Thanks you!

Comment: I would go with a trigger.  It would probably only take 5 lines of code to update a field when the record is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many who commented suspected, there was a Workflow in place that was modifying the objects.  I am going with a "Save" Workflow that will update a custom date/time field. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use ModifiedById field.